# Two arrays match them and display unmatched

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays `$jlist` and `$vlist`, I need to display the unmatched entries.

```
if($jlist==$vlist) echo ''; 
else echo $vlist;
```

my looping attempts have failed along with using the foreach method. Please advise.

```
if(count($jlist)>0)&&(count($vlist)>0)
{
    foreach($jlist as $j)&&($vlist as $v)
    {
        if($v==$j)echo '';
        else 
            echo '<option>'.$v.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: So have you tried array_diff()? (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: no but I will research that

Comment: try `array_diff()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(count($jlist)>0 && count($vlist)>0)
{
  $new_list=array_diff($jlist,$vlist);
  foreach($new_list as $j)
  {
    echo '<option>'.$j.'</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some comments? It helps to understand your proposal.

Comment: Your comment is not respectful. Indeed, you're not doing any freelancing, even better, you are supposed to be helping the community. Of course you are free to not leave any comment but you're answering to help others yes? And your answer will be even clearer if you explain what you are doing. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the elements of the first array which are not in the second one, you should try `array_diff($jlist, $vlist)` inverting the array order if you wanted the elements of the second array which are not present in the first one.

If you are looking for both, then you just have to merge the two results, like `array_merge(array_diff($jlist, $vlist), array_diff($vlist, $jlist))`

Answer (score 0):

Check it out

```
foreach($jlist as $j)
{

    if(!in_array($j,$vlist))
            echo $j."<br/>";

}
```

Comment: Care to add some comments? It will help the OP and future visitors to understand your code.